# How do I test if a variable that I declared in an inner block exists in the outer block?

Tags: python

Given this sample Python code:

```
for item in items:
    if somecondition(item):
        requireditem = item
        break

# use item
```

How can I know if I'm allowed to access `requireditem` after the loop? i.e. if `somecondition(item)` was `True` for some item in the list.

One solution might be:

```
requireditem = None

for item in items:
    if somecondition(item):
        requireditem = item
        break

if requireditem != None:
    # do something
```

But I'm wondering what's the Pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: Does a `requireditem` always exist? Is there really only one?

Comment: "if requiredItem != None" should be "if not requiredItem".

Comment: @Andrea: No, it should be `requiredItem is not None`. Coercion to boolean considers several values that could be perfectly valid - e.g. empty collections - falsy. And singletons should be checked for with `is` so an `__eq__` overload can't get into your way.

Comment: @Felix: there may be more than one, and it might not exist

Comment: @jackson: Then your approach is not correct anyway, as `requireditem` will only have a reference to *one* element (the last one that matches the condition). @Amber gave the best answer in this case.

Comment: @Felix: yeah, I forgot the `break` in my pseudo code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing anything else in the loop? Are you setting `somevar` to anything besides `True`? If not, perhaps this would be better:

```
if any(somecondition(item) for item in items):
    # do something
```

There's no real need for a variable.

#### From your edit:

There's still a better way to do this:

```
required_items = [item for item in items if somecondition(item)]
if required_items:
    # do something
    # if only one required item is ever present, then maybe...
    required_item = required_items[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (but was your question more related to variable scoping?)

`somevar = [item for item in items if somecondition(item)]`

```
if somevar:
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called "variable scope".

Here is a nice article that explains it well for new programmers.
http://www.digital-web.com/articles/variable_scope_for_new_programmers/

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with scoping. There's only one scope involved here. In some other languages there would be a new scope created by the loop, but that's not the case in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know if there is a way to test if the local variable exists, you can do so by handling the `UnboundLocalError` exception:

```
try:
    somevar
except UnboundLocalError:
    print "Variable does not exist"
else:
    print "Variable exists"
```

But this is certainly not considered "pythonic". Don't do that. Either set the variable to `None` beforehand or use a different approach altogether.

One solution would be to make use of Python's `for-else` construct:

```
for item in items:
   if somecondition(item):
       break
else:
   raise NoSuitableItemFound()  # If no break occurred.
```

Comment: No, you don't want to catch `UnboundLocalError`. You simply don't. Programmer hell is no jest.

Answer (score 0):

For the edited question, you could use

```
try:
    requireditem = next(item for item in items if somecondition(item))
except StopIteration:
    # error handling, no item found
else:
    # do something with requireditem
```

This will traverse `items` only until the first matching item is found, in contrast to the solutions using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

For the minimum change to your code, just do whatever it is you want to do in the loop body and then break out. You should probably be breaking out on the first match anyway (unless you want to always scan the entire list and need the *last* item satisfying your condition).

```
for item in items:
    if somecondition(item):
        # do something with item
        break
```

However, there are better ways to do this depending on exactly what you want to do (others have posted such solutions).